# Data Visualisation - D3 - Setting up local file structure

Tags: d3.js

Good afternoon.
I am new in respect of D3 data visualization library.
I have some problems when I load the D3 from a local folder (when I use the D3 link everything is ok), I need to know where I need to copy the the D3 folder in my computer.

Regards

Comment: Please add how you are referencing the library in your markup (when loading from local).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `html` document is in a `myfolder` folder, and you have a folder called `mbostock-d3` inside, and inside that `mbostock-d3` folder you have all the files from the D3.js release you are using, it could be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="mbostock-d3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- your html content goes here -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    // your D3.js script could go (ie) here
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps, boa sorte! ;)

Comment: Theoretically where is supposed to be the hml file?
In the project folder or in the local host folder?

Comment: It depends if you are using a local webserver or not. If you are, the HTML file should be in your localhost root folder (or any other inside of it). If you aren't using a local server, it doesn't matter where you have the HTML document, as long as the `mbostock-d3` folder and respective content is in the same folder as that HTML document.